# Convert Binary PDF Stream, to base64 (server side)

Tags: javascript, pdf, base64, binaryfiles, binary-data

As the title says , i am looking for a way to convert Binary Stream PDF data to Base64 on the server side.

The concept is that i am doing a https request to a service and it returns me a binary response which ALSO contains PDF data that i need to make a file of .

e.g

```
  %PDF-1.5
%����
4 0 obj
<<
/Type/XObjcect
/Subtype/Image
/Width 799
/Height 70
/ColorSpace/DeviceGray
/BitsPerComponent 8
/Filter/FlateDecode
/Length 5181
>>
stream
x���=H#�������A�&�)���B���4iba�&O8H
.
.
. 
(rest here)
```

The software I am working with , does not accept this format in order to create a PDF file inside the system.

**What i want to do :**

I need to convert this stream to base64 and inject it into an XML which I have no problem doing ,taking into account i have the base64 format of this PDF .

I ve seen many PDF libraries but most of them work browser side and convert from a PDF file from a URL or Path and not an actual binary stream .

Any help is much appreciated.

EDIT :  [Actual data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLbI0.png)

Comment: https://github.com/mazira/base64-stream https://www.npmjs.com/package/encode-image-stream https://github.com/davidmarkclements/base64-encode-stream

Comment: @robertklep Hello , sorry for replying back as these github repos are basically doing what i want but since i am developing for cloud platforms , i cannot really understand node . 

I have edited my post to include the Actual data that i have . It is basically an array containing  Binary data extracted from PDF-  to %EOF. Now all i need to do is create a base64 out of that or even an image that will display the Label ( its basically a label )

Comment: You expect us to do this for you?

Comment: @KJ Thats pretty helpful . This is what i am currently doing yet it my app crashes when trying to create a file with that binary encoded in base64

Comment: @KJ Correct . The basic idea is to create a base64 string out of the binary pdf so that i can display it by dynamically injecting it inside an XML document pdf source data:application/pdf;base64, base64string here .

Thats what i am doing and still it is crushing , i will spend few hours on this today as well and if i come up with any solution i will post it here for future reference .
Thanks KJ.

Answer (score 1):

Turned out the Binary response was returning me 2 < pdf > when i was splitting from PDF- to %%EOF .

The first part encoded was returning me a really bad base64 not even starting with JVBER .

Concatenating both parts was returning me a base64 string which was showing Blank page .

The solution was to isolate only the 2nd PDF base64Encode it and then injecting it dynamically to an XML form < pdf source  data:application/pdf;base64,'JVBER..........................' > and rendering the XML to a PDF .

Now everything is displaying perfectly.